# Why does "e" occur in forms of 'vōs' but not 'nōs'?

Tags: pronunciation, language-evolution, pronouns

The forms of *nōs* and *vōs* exhibit a pattern, except in the genitive (*n**o**strī/um*, *v**e**strī/um*) and the possessive (*n**o**ster*, *v**e**ster*). Did *vōs* originally resemble *nōs* in all its forms, only to diverge later? If so, what caused the change, and why did *nōs* remain the same while *vōs* changed (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the forms of *vōs* did originally resemble those of *nōs*. But there was a sound change in Latin whereby the sequence *vo* became *ve*; this is an example of [dissimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissimilation). Apparently this only occurred when the *o* was short, which is why it did not happen in the word *vōs* itself. Other examples are *adversum, veto*, which were originally *advorsum, voto*.

Weiss (*Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin*, p. 140) states that this change only took place when *ve* was followed by a dental, and that, based on inscriptional evidence, it occurred in the second century BC.